# Email bounce notification for an email account that doesn’t exist in exim mail server

Tags: email, email-server, exim, email-bounces

Need help with **Exim** mail server setting.

I want to set the exim mail server to trigger an email bounce notification for an email account that doesn’t exist. For example: abc@abc.com - should bounce immediately.

When I try the same using my outlook using my personal email account – I get an immediate bounce notification.

Is there a setting with exim configuration?

Comment: The verification of a recipient address is an [ACL](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html) option. See for instance chapter 44. Address verification: ... `verify = recipient/defer_ok/callout=10s,defer_ok` ...

Comment: Where i can put this setting via WHM -> Exim configuration -> Advance editor
or
How do i edit in exim.conf

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment to your question, the Exim Documentation covers address validation.

Bouncing particular addresses can be done easily by adding an alias to `/etc/aliases`.  This is usually the first router for local addresses submitted remotely.  (For local submissions, there may a router for 'real-' local addresses.) The alias can include a message as well.  These are some variations I have used:

```
abc    :  :fail: 
abc    :  :fail:  Leaked to spammers
abc    :  :fail:  Try abc@example.com 
abc    :  :fail:  Unrouteable address
abc    :  :fail:  Please contact postmaster
```

Comment: I don't need for specific domain like abc but for any domain.

Comment: @VikramPote You would need a lookup ahead of the remote delivery routers that looks up the address with the domain.  This is all documented in the Exim documentation and FAQs.